# Run every file in a folder with Docker

Tags: python, docker

I have a dockerfile and I want to run every python script in a folder without naming each one, just run every python script in that folder

how can I do so?

Comment: Are they long running python jobs or want to run in sequence one after the other? Can you add more details?

Comment: How would you do it outside of a Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7.2-alpine3.8

WORKDIR /opt

COPY . /opt

RUN find . -name "*.py" | xargs -n 1 python3
```

**Python files**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

print("1")
```

**Command**

```
docker build -t temp .
```

**Output**

```
....
Step 4/5 : RUN find . -name "*.py" | xargs -n 1 python3
---> Running in 68326b65cdda
1
2
```

1 and 2 are the result of 1.py and 2.py